# No heading for reference/bibilography part

Tags: bibliographies, naming, elsarticle

I run pdflatex, bibtex, and twice pdflatex on the minimal working .tex and .bib files in [Installing new .bst files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83370/861). It can compile, and the output pdf file has the reference part but without the heading "References" or "Bibliography", see

[image]

I wonder why and how to solve the problem?

Thanks.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[nodots]{numcompress}

\biboptions{sort&compress}

\journal{A Journal}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{My Title}

\author[myaddr]{Author 1}
\author[myaddr]{Author 2}
\address[myaddr]{An Address}

\begin{abstract}
Here's an abstract.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}
keyword1 \sep keyword2 \sep keyword3
\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}
\section{Introduction}
\label{intro}

I would like to cite~\cite{Lehockey1998,Lehockey1997,Norton1996,Lehockey1999}. I would also like to cite~\cite{Lehockey1998,Lehockey1997,Thaveeprungsriporn1997,Lehockey1999,Gupta2004,Tan2008,Tan2008a}.

\bibliographystyle{model1a-num-names}
%\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{MyReferences}

\end{document}
```

Here is a corresponding .bib file:

```
@article{Lehockey1997,
author = {Lehockey, E M and Palumbo, G},
doi = {10.1016/S0921-5093(97)00126-3},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Ollie/Documents/Mendeley Desktop/Lehockey, Palumbo/Lehockey, Palumbo - On the creep behaviour of grain boundary engineered nickel 1 - 1997.pdf:pdf},
issn = {09215093},
journal = {Materials Science and Engineering: A},
month = sep,
number = {2},
pages = {168--172},
title = {{On the creep behaviour of grain boundary engineered nickel 1}},
url = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0921509397001263},
volume = {237},
year = {1997}
}
@article{Lehockey1998,
author = {Lehockey, E M and Palumbo, G and Lin, P},
doi = {10.1007/s11661-998-0214-y},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Ollie/Documents/Mendeley Desktop/Lehockey, Palumbo, Lin/Lehockey, Palumbo, Lin - Improving the weldability and service performance of nickel-and iron-based superalloys by grain boundary engineering - 1998.pdf:pdf},
issn = {1073-5623},
journal = {Metallurgical and Materials Transactions A},
month = dec,
number = {12},
pages = {3069--3079},
title = {{Improving the weldability and service performance of nickel-and iron-based superalloys by grain boundary engineering}},
url = {http://www.springerlink.com/index/10.1007/s11661-998-0214-y},
volume = {29},
year = {1998}
}
@article{Lehockey1999,
author = {Lehockey, E M and Limoges, D and Palumbo, G and Sklarchuk, J and Tomantschger, K and Vincze, A},
doi = {10.1016/S0378-7753(99)00015-4},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Ollie/Documents/Mendeley Desktop/Lehockey et al/Lehockey et al. - On improving the corrosion and growth resistance of positive Pb-acid battery grids by grain boundary engineering - 1999.pdf:pdf},
issn = {03787753},
journal = {Journal of Power Sources},
keywords = {grain boundary engineering,ignition,intergranular corrosion,lighting,starting},
month = mar,
number = {1-2},
pages = {79--83},
title = {{On improving the corrosion and growth resistance of positive Pb-acid battery grids by grain boundary engineering}},
url = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0378775399000154},
volume = {78},
year = {1999}
}
@article{Norton1996,
author = {Norton, D. P. and Goyal, A. and Budai, J. D. and Christen, D. K. and Kroeger, D. M. and Specht, E. D. and He, Q. and Saffian, B. and Paranthaman, M. and Klabunde, C. E. and Lee, D. F. and Sales, B. C. and List, F. A.},
doi = {10.1126/science.274.5288.755},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Ollie/Documents/Mendeley Desktop/Norton et al/Norton et al. - Epitaxial YBa2Cu3O7 on Biaxially Textured Nickel (001) An Approach to Superconducting Tapes with High Critical Current Density - 1996.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0036-8075},
journal = {Science},
month = nov,
number = {5288},
pages = {755--757},
title = {{Epitaxial YBa2Cu3O7 on Biaxially Textured Nickel (001): An Approach to Superconducting Tapes with High Critical Current Density}},
url = {http://www.sciencemag.org/cgi/doi/10.1126/science.274.5288.755},
volume = {274},
year = {1996}
}
@article{Thaveeprungsriporn1997,
author = {Thaveeprungsriporn, Visit and Was, Gary S.},
doi = {10.1007/s11661-997-0167-6},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Ollie/Documents/Mendeley Desktop/Thaveeprungsriporn, Was/Thaveeprungsriporn, Was - The role of coincidence-site-lattice boundaries in creep of Ni-16Cr-9Fe at 360 °C - 1997.pdf:pdf},
issn = {1073-5623},
journal = {Metallurgical and Materials Transactions A},
month = oct,
number = {10},
pages = {2101--2112},
title = {{The role of coincidence-site-lattice boundaries in creep of Ni-16Cr-9Fe at 360 °C}},
url = {http://www.springerlink.com/index/78285142G7358665.pdf http://www.springerlink.com/index/10.1007/s11661-997-0167-6},
volume = {28},
year = {1997}
}
@article{Gupta2004,
author = {Gupta, Gaurav and Was, Gary S. and Alexandreanu, Bogdan},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Ollie/Documents/Mendeley Desktop/Gupta, Was, Alexandreanu/Gupta, Was, Alexandreanu - Grain boundary engineering of ferritic-martensitic alloy T91 - 2004.pdf:pdf},
journal = {Metallurgical and Materials Transactions A},
number = {February},
pages = {717--719},
title = {{Grain boundary engineering of ferritic-martensitic alloy T91}},
url = {http://www.springerlink.com/index/X78241U5601Q0510.pdf},
volume = {35},
year = {2004}
}
@article{Tan2008,
author = {Tan, L and Ren, X and Sridharan, K and Allen, T.R.},
doi = {10.1016/j.corsci.2008.08.024},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Ollie/Documents/Mendeley Desktop/Tan et al/Tan et al. - Corrosion behavior of Ni-base alloys for advanced high temperature water-cooled nuclear plants - 2008.pdf:pdf},
issn = {0010938X},
journal = {Corrosion Science},
month = nov,
number = {11},
pages = {3056--3062},
publisher = {Elsevier Ltd},
title = {{Corrosion behavior of Ni-base alloys for advanced high temperature water-cooled nuclear plants}},
url = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0010938X08003363},
volume = {50},
year = {2008}
}
@article{Tan2008a,
author = {Tan, L and Sridharan, K and Allen, T.R. and Nanstad, R.K. and McClintock, D.A.},
doi = {10.1016/j.jnucmat.2007.08.015},
file = {:C$\backslash$:/Users/Ollie/Documents/Mendeley Desktop/Tan et al/Tan et al. - Microstructure tailoring for property improvements by grain boundary engineering - 2008.pdf:pdf},
issn = {00223115},
journal = {Journal of Nuclear Materials},
month = feb,
number = {1-2},
pages = {270--280},
title = {{Microstructure tailoring for property improvements by grain boundary engineering}},
url = {http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0022311507009646},
volume = {374},
year = {2008}
}
```

Comment: Please post an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001).

Answer (score 2):

That's just the way it is with [`elsarticle`](http://ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle) - it defines `\bibliography` to not print a section. You can insert it manually though:

```
\section*{\bibname}% ...or \section*{\refname}
\bibliographystyle{..}
\bibliography{..}
```

...or force it directly using `\section*{Bibliography}` (or `\section*{References}`).

Comment: thanks. `\section*{References}` doesn't make `References` appear  in the outline/bookmark of the resulting pdf. Can I make it appear? Or which alternative to `elsarticle` can work?

Comment: @Tim: Then use `\section*{\refname} \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\refname}` (and compile at least twice on the first go).